# Creating a Dynamic web project of existing code I've pulled from the repository with HgEclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, hgeclipse

I've installed the HgEclipse plugin, now I'm just wondering how I can create a dynamic web project out of the code I've pulled from the repository with HgEclipse?